# How to logout and redirect to login page using Laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I am using Laravel 5.4 and trying to implement authentication system. I used php artisan command make:auth to setup it. I edited the views according to my layout. Now, when I am trying to logout it throwing me this error

NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

could any one help me how to logout?

Comment: Post your code to?

Answer (score 194, accepted):

In your `web.php` (routes):

**add:**

```
Route::get('logout', '\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout');
```

In your `LoginController.php`

**add:**

```
public function logout(Request $request) {
  Auth::logout();
  return redirect('/login');
}
```

Also, in the top of `LoginController.php`, after `namespace`

**add:**

```
use Auth;
```

Now, you are able to logout using `yourdomain.com/logout` URL or if you have created `logout button`, add href to `/logout`

Comment: Why not use laravel pre-built `auth routes`?

Comment: I've found this is no longer sufficient, you should also add `$request->session()->invalidate();` to the logout function - this prevents some weird scenarios I encountered.

Comment: It works! But @Sid answer below is best (and fastest) option

Comment: `Request $request` do nothing here.

Comment: This is the best answer ever in this topic! I have tried 5 other different ways to do this and failed each time. This works perfectly!!!

Comment: logout should never be a GET route. Should be a form with a unique token.

Answer (score 69):

Well even if what suggest by @Tauras just works I don't think it's the correct way to deal with this.

You said you have run `php artisan make:auth` which should have also inserted `Auth::routes();` in your `routes/web.php` routing files. Which comes with default `logout` route already defined and is named `logout`.

You can [**see it here on GitHub**](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php), but I will also report the code here for simplicity:

```
    /**
     * Register the typical authentication routes for an application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function auth()
    {
        // Authentication Routes...
        $this->get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
        $this->post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
        $this->post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
        // Registration Routes...
        $this->get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
        $this->post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');
        // Password Reset Routes...
        $this->get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
        $this->post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
        $this->get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
        $this->post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
    }
```

Then again please note that `logout` **requires** `POST` as HTTP request method. There are many valid reason behind this, but just to mention one very important is that in this way you can prevent **cross-site request forgery**.

So according to what I have just pointed out a correct way to implement this could be just this:

```
<a href="{{ route('logout') }}" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('frm-logout').submit();">
    Logout
</a>    
<form id="frm-logout" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
</form>
```

Finally note that I have inserted laravel out of the box ready function `{{ csrf_field() }}`!

Comment: using event field is deprecated; what to replace with?

Comment: How would you logout using just an anchor tag when there is no form involved?

Comment: Thanks for providing form example that works great, saved me time!

Answer (score 24):

You can use the following in your controller:

```
return redirect('login')->with(Auth::logout());
```

Comment: This should be an accepted answer. Works like a charm!

Comment: This makes no sense. `with()` is for flashing data to the session and takes a string or array. Why would you put `Auth::logout()` there? It doesn't even return anything, as its return type is void.

Comment: This still works with Laravel >8 like charm

Answer (score 15):

**Best way for Laravel 5.8**

100% worked

Add this function inside your **Auth\LoginController.php**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

And also add this

```
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    $this->guard()->logout();

    $request->session()->invalidate();

    return $this->loggedOut($request) ?: redirect('/login');
}
```

Comment: How to prevent from using "Back" function from the browser, I still can accessed the last page but cannot operate the fitures. I only get this error `Trying to get property 'name' of non-object `. I also using laravel 5.8.

Comment: note that you need to import Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers

Comment: @Kris for this you need to pass no-cache to response for all auth routes. The back button works with cache. So once you click back on browser it pops from cache.

Answer (score 10):

here is another way to do it by calling Auth::logout() in route

```
Route::get('/logout', function(){
   Auth::logout();
   return Redirect::to('login');
});
```

Answer (score 6):

I recommend you stick with Laravel auth routes in web.php: `Auth::routes()`

It will create the following route:

```
POST | logout | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout
```

You will need to logout using a POST form. This way you will also need the CSRF token which is recommended.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('logout') }}">
  @csrf
  <button type="submit">Logout</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 5):

**In Laravel 6.2**

Add the following route to :  **web.php**

```
Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
```

Using Achor tag with logout using a POST form. This way you will also need the CSRF token.

```
 <a class="log-out-btn" href="#" onclick="event.preventDefault();document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();"> Logout </a>

 <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
          {{ csrf_field() }}
  </form>
```

Comment: this is the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

In 5.5

adding

`Route::get('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');`

to my routes file works fine.

Comment: don't do this, see the response of Sid. Other websites can log users out while redirecting someone to domain.com/logout

Answer (score 2):

I know this question was asked for old version of laravel. I want to share my solution for **Laravel 8.65** version.
In **AuthenticatedSessionControler** update destroy function like this.

```
public function destroy(Request $request)
{
    Auth::guard('web')->logout();
    $request->session()->invalidate();
    $request->session()->regenerateToken();
    return redirect('/admin');
}
```

update your last line from `return redirect('/')` to `return redirect('/admin');`

Answer (score 1):

It's better and safer to add to your LoginController.php the following code, that runs only after the standard logout:

```
use AuthenticatesUsers;

protected function loggedOut(Request $request)
    {
        return redirect('/new/redirect/you/want');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone is interested on this topic for Laravel 8 or 9.

As you can read on the Laravel documentation on https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authentication#logging-out

In addition to Auth::logout(), you will need to invalidate the user's session and regenerate their CSRF token:

```
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    Auth::logout();
 
    $request->session()->invalidate();
 
    $request->session()->regenerateToken();
 
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you used the auth scaffolding in 5.5 simply direct your `href` to:

```
{{ route('logout') }}
```

There is no need to alter any routes or controllers.

Comment: doesn't work when I try it. Laravel throw an error `Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message`

Comment: @BariqDharmawan It's because the logout route is a POST route, which means you have to put it in a form. Ex., method="POST" action="{{ route('logout') }}"

Answer (score 0):

### In Laravel 9

go to routes directory open web.php and write logout route:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController;
Route::get('logout', [LoginController::class,'logout']);
```

From blade add logout URL

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href={{route('logout')}}>Logout</a>
```

### Notice

logout function will redirect to home page `/`

If you want to redirect to login page you should override on logout function in **`App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php`**

```
public function logout(){  
   return redirect('login')->with(Auth::logout());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

if you are looking to do it via code on specific conditions, here is the solution worked for me. I have used in middleware to block certain users:
these lines from below is the actual code to logout:

```
$auth = new LoginController();
$auth->logout($request);
```

Complete File:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
use Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController;
class ExcludeCustomers{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next){
        $user = Auth::guard()->user();
        if( $user->role == 3 ) {
            $auth = new LoginController();
            $auth->logout($request);
            header("Location: https://google.com");
            die();
        } 
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```